# ButtonBar handles row overflow?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `ButtonBar` inside a Card.
I would like to insert buttons until the end of the card then they will go on a new line.

Only problem is the overflow.

I read that `ButtonBar` can handle the overflow and go on a new line to continue the insertion, is this true? How can I do this?

Do you think is better to handle this situation with `Row`?

```
child: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.94,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.3,
            child : Card(
              elevation: 3.0,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(0,-1),
                    child : ButtonBar(
                      overflowDirection: ,
                      //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: null,
                          child: Text("One",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          disabledColor: Colors.orange,
                          ),
                        new RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: null,
                          child: Text("Two",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          disabledColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                        ),
                          new RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: null,
                            child: Text("Three",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                            disabledColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
                              ),
                        new RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Four",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          disabledColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        new RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Five",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          disabledColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                 ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it with `ButtonBar`

Example

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonBar(
      alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: List.generate(
        7,
        (index) => RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text("Button $index"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output:
[With ButtonBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0hcl.png)

But I think what you are looking for is `Wrap`
Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      spacing: 2.0,
      children: List.generate(
        50,
        (index) => RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text("Button $index"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output: [With Wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpCNS.png)

Comment: Yeah this is what I needed, I would like to create some space between all the buttons inside the wrap, do you know how I can do it?

Comment: I dit it, there is "Spacing" inside Wrap, it allow me to create some distance between the elements inside it.

Comment: Yes...spacing is the example I gave. @MichealRoss upvote?